# WebGL - Пропадают задние грани полупрозрачного куба

Tags: webgl

Прошу помочь тех кто сталкивался или знает как решить проблему:

Суть: есть вращающийся куб с полупрозрачными гранями http://ddbase.ru/gltest/

При вращении, пропадают некоторые задние грани, как этого избежать? Какая установка или что?

Используемые установки webGL

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {alpha: true, antialias: false});
...............
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: У треугольников есть такая штука, как лицевая и обратная сторона. По умолчанию рисуется лицевая. Можно включить режим, чтобы рисовались обе. К сожалению с webgl не знаком, но с 3d работал.  http://www.gamedev.ru/faq/?id=6 данная ссылка вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу два варианта:

1. `gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);` - аналог команды `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` из обычного OpenGL. Это отключит отбрасывание граней, расположенных обратной стороной, при этом снизив производительность.
2. вручную разворачивать нужные грани.